# How can I hide a column in ag-grid but include it in export to CSV?

Tags: reactjs, csv, ag-grid-react

I am using ag-grid with React, and this is my code to export to CSV at the moment:

```
    exportToCsv() {
    let params = {
      fileName: this.state.fileName,
      processCellCallback: this.formatCsv.bind(this),
      columnGroups: true
    }
    this.api.exportDataAsCsv(params)
  }
```

If I hide some columns in Ag-Grid, they don't show up in the CSV. Is there a way to hide the columns on the website, but have them show up in CSV?

Alternatively, if I convert the data in those columns to tooltips, can they be included in the CSV?

Answer (score 1):

Define all the columns to display on CSV in columnKeys within params for export